# Receiving a syntax error for this SQL code

Tags: mysql, sql

Syntax error:-

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER (
CustomerID        Int    NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
CustomerName      Char(25)                      NOT NULL,
CustomerDeliveryAddress  Char(25)               NOT NULL,                                       
CustomerPhone            Char (10)              NOT NULL,
CustomerBillingAddress   Char(25)               NOT NULL,
CustomerCreditCard       Int                    NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT  CustomerPK          PRIMARY KEY(CustomerID)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

In mysql there is nothing named identity, instead there is AUTO_INCREMENT

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER (
CustomerID        INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY, 
CustomerName      Char(25)                      NOT NULL,
CustomerDeliveryAddress  Char(25)               NOT NULL,                                       
CustomerPhone            Char (10)              NOT NULL,
CustomerBillingAddress   Char(25)               NOT NULL,
CustomerCreditCard       Int                    NOT NULL

);
```

Answer (score 1):

u have to declare primary key only once

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER (
CustomerID        INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
CustomerName      Char(25)                      NOT NULL,
CustomerDeliveryAddress  Char(25)               NOT NULL,
CustomerPhone            Char (10)              NOT NULL,
CustomerBillingAddress   Char(25)               NOT NULL,
CustomerCreditCard       Int                    NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(CustomerID));
```

Comment: Do I still need this? CONSTRAINT  CustomerPK          PRIMARY KEY(CustomerID)

Comment: their is nothing to use any other thing just write PRIMARY KEY(customerID)@RhettClaypool